# How can I send a document to the system print dialog on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, printing

I am wondering if there is a way to use the system print dialog on Mac to print PDF documents.

Everything I have seen so far involved either using `lpr` or was only valid on Windows.

Particularly, once I have the dialog, I would like to change the print options, possibly even selecting the printer-specific "staple" options (on a Xerox WorkCentre).

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a python script that opens a document in Preview, and presents the Print dialog? (There is no 'system' print dialog as such.) You don't want a script that sets your staple options automatically and prints the document without user input?

Comment: Hi @benwiggy - actually the latter - I want a python script that prints a PDF with staple option, without user input. I thought there must be a generic print dialog, but apparently there isn't.

Comment: So any reason why lpr isn't ideal? You can specify job options with th -o flag, if I remember correctly. Obviously, you have to find out what the exact wording is for staples on your Xerox...

Comment: @benwiggy - using lpr with -o was what I first tried, but I could not find any documentation of the -o flags for that Xerox printer... That's why I thought I try to go through the print dialog. There has to be a generic way, Preview does not know about stapling, but it is possible to staple pages using the appropriate "Xerox Features" in the print dialog.

Comment: I did find this document, which describes using lpr on an old Xerox printer. http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/docs/DC240_DC250/userdocs/any-os/en/Using_lpr_Utilities_for_DOS_and_Unix.pdf Things might have changed. Alternatively, the keywords in the printer's PPD file should work as options.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, I will try it first thing when I am back in the office!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a much better way, but this might get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Open PDF in Preview app
open FileToPrint.pdf

# Tell Preview to print it
osascript<<EOF
tell application "System Events"
   tell process "Preview"
      delay 1
      keystroke "p" using command down
      --delay 1
      --keystroke return
      --delay 10
      --keystroke "w" using command down
  end tell
end tell
EOF
```

The lines starting with `--` are comments, so remove the `--` to actually go ahead and print the document without further interaction being required.

If that `open` command doesn't happen to open in **Preview**, you can force it with:

```
open -a Preview FileToPrint.pdf
```

Comment: You could use AppleScript's `print` command, plus `print dialog true`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about osascript, seems to be very powerful!

Comment: @benwiggy If you know an Applescript `print` command, please add an answer saying how to invoke it, including from where and how any parameters work.